# iPhone SDK - opening links in a UITextView in a web view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitextview, datadetectortypes

I have specified dataDetectorTypes on a UITextView so that URLs open in Safari when touched.

Is it possible to intercept this behaviour so I load the URL in a UIWebView instead?  Or would I have write my own URL detector code to re-route this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do the URL detection yourself and manually load the UIWebView when the URL is tapped.

Everything needs to be custom-done because Apple sends all `http://` and `https://` URL openings to Safari.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above that works best is the replacement of method implementation for [UIApplication openURL:]

Another way to achieve that, without using runtime.h is to subclass UIApplication.  Then, override the openURL: selector.  With this approach, you can call [super openURL:] from your subclass for URLs you want the default handling for.  It also seems a little cleaner to me since you don't need to mess with the internal method implementations of the classes.

If you choose this approach, though, there are 2 other important steps.  In the main.m file you need to change the 3rd argument to the UIApplicationMain function call so that it matches the name of your subclass:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplicationSubclass", nil);
```

Also, you should probably change the class of the File's Owner in your MainWindow.xib file from UIApplication to your subclass.

Comment: This works perfectly for those who want to have their own implementation through out the application. I have found it really useful

Answer (score 1):

I did everyone a favor and answered your question with a blog post and demo app.

`http://52apps.net/post/879106231/method-swizzling-uitextview-and-safari`
`http://github.com/marksands/UITextViewLinkOptions`

To expand on tt.Kilew's post, you create the category, but call your method something else such as `customOpenURL`. When you want to go back to Safari you do something called Method Swizzling. It looks like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
..
Method customOpenUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(customOpenURL:));
Method openUrl = class_getInstanceMethod([UIApplication class], @selector(openURL:));
method_exchangeImplementations(customOpenUrl, openUrl);
```

Just call this method to swap the `openURL` implementation with your `customOpenURL` implementation when you do and don't want to use Safari.

Check out the [demo app](http://github.com/marksands/UITextViewLinkOptions) for more detail. Hope this helps! :)

### Edit

If you don't want to risk your app getting rejected, you might want to check out a custom UITextView I developed to better suit the situation: https://github.com/marksands/MSTextView

Comment: Nice - don't know if anything has changed lately, but someone's app that used the Three20 framework was rejected for method swizzling (I believe Three20 was updated to not use it anymore). http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/ea606b4114565e75

Comment: Right you are! I started implementing a custom UITextView to handle URLs better. This method works better and won't get rejected by apple. You can check out the project here https://github.com/marksands/MSTextView

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer :) That works fine for me is to re-implement UIApplication openURL:(NSURL *) url

```
@interface UIApplication (Private)

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url;

@end

@implementation UIApplication (Private)

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url {
   // all viewcontrollers should change currentViewController to self
   if ([MyWatcher currentViewController]) {
      // Do anything you want
      [[MyWatcher handleURL:url withController:[MyWatcher currentViewController]];
      return YES;
   }
   return NO;
}

@end

... Some view controller
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [MyWatcher setCurrentController:self];
}
```

Comment: I found this link which will show you what MyWatcher is - I just stumbled upon it when looking for an answer - https://github.com/marksands/UITextViewLinkOptions/blob/master/Classes/UITextViewLinkOptionsAppDelegate.m#L14-22

Comment: Is there any risk of Apple rejecting the app if I do this? The thing worrying me is "Private". What does it do here?

Comment: You can name category any way you like. openURL is not private method at all. Anotheroption is to subclass UIApplication with your own implementation and use method overrriding instead of category

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

Your standard UITextView setup should look something like this, don't forget the delegate and dataDetectorTypes.

```
var textView = UITextView(x: 10, y: 10, width: CardWidth - 20, height: placeholderHeight) //This is my custom initializer
textView.text = "dsfadsaf www.google.com"
textView.selectable = true
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
textView.delegate = self
addSubview(textView)
```

After your class ends add this piece:
Note that you need https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController this library, which is the best one out there as far as I know.

```
class myVC: UIViewController {
    //viewdidload and other stuff here
}

extension MainCard: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        //Do your stuff over here
        var webViewController = SVModalWebViewController(URL: URL)
        view.presentViewController(webViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try implementing `application:handleOpenURL:` in your Application Delegate.
This method should get called whenever a url gets opened. Here you should be able to make the URL open in your webview.