# open linkin UITextView in my UIWebView on another tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, hyperlink

i have searched this site back and forth withoutfinding a clear answer for what i want.

i have a detail view which is presented after pressing a cell in a table view, this has a uitextview which displays the content of the cell. in most cases this text will have a url link, which when pressed opens the page in safari.

what i want to do is open the link in a UIWebView which i hae on another tab within my app, is it possible to push this link onto my uiwebview insteadof opening safari?

i am fairly new to coding, all self taught. so if you could explain with some detail itwill be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [iPhone SDK - opening links in a UITextView in a web view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889262/iphone-sdk-opening-links-in-a-uitextview-in-a-web-view)