# Xcode, Swift: How to detect link click and stop redirecting Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari

I created a new blank `Single View Application` with an `UITextView` that contains the link `https://example.com`.

When running my app, it auto detects that link and makes it blue. When clicking on this link, it gets opened in Apple Safari Browser.

How can I detect the link click and stop redirecting to Safari?

I tried the following code:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
    print("Link clicked!")
    return false
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting the `print("Link clicked!")` in console and it's still redirecting to Safari.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will prevent the URL to get opened in Safari and will print the link in console:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var myTextViewAction: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextViewAction.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        print("\nThis link was clicked: \(URL.absoluteString)\n")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an UITextView, NOT WebView. I guess, this is why `webView()` isn't get called then clicking on a link in an `UITextView`.

Comment: Ok, then it has nothing to do with the method you wrote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032788/8447312 take a look at this answer, its objective C but just get the method name, and try to see if you can prevent opening in safari

Comment: @David I've updated the answer. I've tested, and it works. Please test it and accept my answer.

Comment: @ppalancica I'm still testing but it seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @ppalancica How can I get the clicked link?

Comment: @David URL.absoluteString inside that Delegate Method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184961/discussion-between-ppalancica-and-david).